# Oracle to SQL Server Data Transfer Connection Bottleneck

Tags: c#, sql-server, oracle

On a daily basis I import millions of rows of data from an Oracle database over the internet to a local SQL Server database using Attunity. Performance has been rather dismal (not using anywhere near our dismal local internet connection speed of 20Mbps.)

I am trying to find the bottleneck, and figure a way around it. I think I may have found the bottleneck, and I think it's a limit on the transfer speed per connection?

I found it by testing import speed by creating a C# application that creates parallel connections to Oracle using Oracle's ODP.NET Managed driver (I decided to test in C# because it's easier for me to understand what's going on). When I created five threads each pulling 10k records from the remote Oracle database, the combined throughput was about 80Kbps. When I tried again with fifty threads each pulling the same 10k records, the throughput was about 900Kbps.

Has anyone else experienced this...what appears to be a per-connection limit on data transfer rates? Any solutions other than writing code to execute a thousand threads each pulling it's own data?

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting Import at " + DateTime.Now);
        int rowsPerBatch = 10000;
        int batches = 50;
        List<Task> Tasks = new List<Task>();

            for (int i = 0; i < batches; i++)
            {
                Task mytask = Task.Factory.StartNew<List<DAILY_LOG_DATA>>(() => GetData(i,rowsPerBatch),TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
                Tasks.Add(mytask);
            }
            Exception ex = Tasks.First().Exception;
            Task.WaitAll(Tasks.ToArray());            

        Console.WriteLine("Import Finished at " + DateTime.Now);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    static List<DAILY_LOG_DATA> GetData(int index, int rowsPerBatch)
    {
        Entities myContext = new Entities();
        myContext.Database.Connection.Open();
        int batchIndex = (int)index;
        List<DAILY_LOG_DATA> toReturn =
            (from a in myContext.DAILY_LOG_DATA
                //orderby a.DLSEQUENCE
                select a).Take(rowsPerBatch).ToList();
        myContext.Dispose();
        return toReturn;
    }
}
```

Edit: Added my simple testing code set to run 50 simultaneous threads each retrieving (probably the same) 10k rows of data (just to test bandwidth)

Comment: Can you post your attempt so far in code?

Comment: Have you profiled the C# code to see where it is spending its time?  My wild guess is that you are fetching relatively few rows at a time so most of your time is spent sending the Oracle server the "please give me the next row" message rather than fetching a larger number of rows at a time and letting the server use all your available bandwidth.  If that's the case, it may be as simple as changing the fetch size (i.e. http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/428152/OracleDataReader-FetchSize-Property)

Comment: Thank you Justin. Stepping through the code doesn't seem to provide me with much (if any) information, as the fetching of the data is done by the Entity framework, so I can see my query, but what Entity Framework actually does to get the data is (as far as I know) unreviewable.